# Can my wife travel to the US with her existing H4 visa in this situation?

Tags: usa, immigration

**Backstory:** I am on H1B visa working in the US currently and I switched my job last year to another employer. My H1B was transferred to this new employer that I am currently working with. My H1B expires in August 2018. My wife has H4 visa from my previous employer. She has traveled to the US once in December 2015 with the H4 from my previous employer. At that time, I was working with the new employer.

**Situation:** She is traveling on August 5th, 2016 and her visa is expiring on September 16th, 2016. Her visa is H4.

Is she ok to travel? Would she face any issues from the immigration since her visa is expiring soon?

Once she is here in August, I am planning to extend her H4 with this new employer of mine.

Comment: If you have received the approval of your new H1b petition, she should enter the US with a copy of that, and she will be admitted until the expiration of that new H1b petition instead of the expiration of the old one.

Comment: Do share what happened in this case if you can

Comment: @pal4life She travelled to the US without any issues. Later we renewed her visa through my new employer before it expired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wife can re-enter the US with her valid visa, and can right up until the day it expires; the visa allows her to enter..  The [US State Department Bureau of Consular Affairs explanation](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/visa-expiration-date.html):

> The visa expiration date is shown on the visa along with the visa issuance date. The time between visa issuance and expiration date is called your visa validity. The visa validity is the length of time you are permitted to travel to a port-of-entry in the United States.

Once she has rejoined you, you would go through the necessary steps to take care of her immigration status and apply for an extension of stay at a [USCIS service center](https://www.uscis.gov/about-us/find-uscis-office).